# Python continuously crashing after Catalina update

Tags: crash, catalina, python

During my regular development tasks, there is no problem with python. I can activate my virtual environments, interpreter and keep on development with no error whatsoever.

However, randomly MacOS pops up "Problem Report for Python" dialog. This is started after I've upgrade to 10.15 Catalina.

I have no idea how to fix it since everything related python is working correctly as far as I can see.

Here is full log [message](https://pastebin.com/UwFLbHiH). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any answer, but a web search for "Invalid dylib load. Clients should not load the unversioned libcrypto dylib as it does not have a stable ABI." turns up several threads, including workarounds.

Comment: Maybe this is included in the message you pasted but I'm not sure. It looks like you ran python by typing python.  If so, try typing python3 and see if it works.

Comment: Are you saying that this error crops up when you are NOT using python? MacOS does use python for a variety of tasks: xattr and some PDF Automator actions, if I remember correctly. Catalina installs both the usual python 2.7 and a version of python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening to me.  I had a cron entry that was running a python3 script in virtual env.

check your crontab for anything running python.   `crontab -l`

Install openssl with brew.  `brew install openssl`.

Then for any script you find in your crontab, make sure it has the openssl lib paths first in the LD_LIBRARY path.  Add this to either the shell script that starts your python script or to your `~/.bashrc` file

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't have any cronjob however, removing and re-installing openssl works.